# Are these groups virtually polycyclic?

Tags: group-theory

Recall that a group $G$ is *polycyclic* if it has a finite series
of subgroups $G = G_0 \rhd G_1 \rhd \cdots \rhd G_k = 1$ for which each factor $G_{i−1}/G_i$ (where $i = 1, \ldots , k$) is finite cyclic or infinite cyclic. A group $G$ is called *virtually polycyclic* if there exists a polycyclic group $H \lhd G$ such that $G/H$ is finite.

The number $h(G)$ of infinite cyclic factors in a series $G = G_0 \rhd G_1 \rhd \cdots \rhd G_k = 1$ with cyclic or finite factors is an invariant of a virtually polycyclic group $G$ (independent of the series), known as the *Hirsch number* of $G$.

I have a question about the following groups: $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_2 $, and $\mathbb{Z}_2 *\mathbb{Z}_2$. Are these groups virtually polycyclic? In fact, under which conditions is a free product a  virtually polycyclic group?

**My try**: $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is a free group of finite rank 2. I have seen somewhere that a free froup of finite rank $>1$ can't be a virtually polycyclic group. So $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is not a virtually polycyclic group.

It is also wellknown that $\mathbb{Z}_2 *\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$. Then $1\lhd \mathbb{Z}\lhd \mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ in which $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}_2 *\mathbb{Z}_2$ is virtually polycyclic with Hirsch number $1$.

My main question so is that when $G*H$ and $G\rtimes H$ of two groups $G$ and $H$ are virtually polycyclic?

Comment: For nontrivial groups $G$ and $H$, $G*H$ is polycyclic only when $|G|=|H|=2$. In all other cases $G*H$ contains a free subgroup of rank $2$, which is not polycyclic. It is straightforward to prove  that $G \rtimes H$ is polycyclic if and only if $G$ and $H$ are.